# How would we provide documentation for ABCjs, if we were to do it?

Tags: discussion

There seems to be a lot of documentation about ABC notation, the github repository, great tutorials, but also a lot of ways to get lost before getting to what interests us more as questions askers and answers writers: how to actually write ABC notation and how to use it.

Would a few answers to this post be sufficient to direct people with questions about how to use it? Would we have a tag?

More importantly, should we actually do it?

Comment: I haven't explored ABCjs much (in fact, I just knew it from the previous meta post), but maybe we can follow something like [what Math.SE has done for MathJax syntax quick guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/174736)?

Answer (score 6):

Really good point, actually. We will need a post on meta, and our about or FAQ needs a link to "how to use ABCjs" otherwise it will be inaccessible to many.

We will need:

- a list of basic syntax
- examples
- advanced usage
- links to further docs

Answer (score 5):

The most basic and essential documentation is *make it obvious that the capability actually exists.* Right now, if I start writing an answer, I can see some icons telling me about formatting options, inserting images, etc, but nothing that tells me I can use ABC.

IMO The next "documentation level" beyond that should be something like this Lilypond Cheat Sheet: http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.16/Documentation/notation/cheat-sheet. Assumes that the user already knows what he/she wants to notate, and give simple examples of how to notate it.

If the "ABC cheat sheet" also has a link to more comprehensive documentation, that is probably enough - but it's important to give a link to *what is actually implemented in ABCjs*.

If ABC is being used for *human* communication, it doesn't matter much if Alice uses notation that Bob hasn't seen before, so long as Bob can make a reasonable guess at what it means, or just ignore it. After all, most humans (with the possible exception of Elaine Gould) use that strategy for reading *any* music notation! But computers don't "use their skill and judgement" in the same way that humans do.

Answer (score 3):

First! The notation have to be indented in the post, with four spaces.

And here are a few links that helped me understand how to use the notation.

- [really eloquent "what is happening here" exemple](https://abcjs.net/)
- [ABCNotation.com blog post on understanding the notation](http://abcnotation.com/blog/2010/01/31/how-to-understand-abc-the-basics/#further)
- [Steve Mansfield's ABC Notation Part 1](http://www.lesession.co.uk/abc/abc_notation.htm) - with links to a more advanced part
- [Steve Mansfield's Proposed Extensions to the ABC Notation](http://www.lesession.co.uk/abc/abc_extensions.htm) - some of those actually seem to be a part of the notation already, the single letter ones.
- [ABCNotation.com examples](http://abcnotation.com/examples)

Comment: "First! The notation have to be indented in the post, with four spaces" - So does Music.SE needs to link to the functionality that the "computing" SE sites use for format computer code in questions and answers?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe create a topic on the documentation beta?  Special dispensation may be required to accomplish this task, as I do not see an [abcjs](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abcjs) tag on Stack Overflow, and a search only yields eleven results right now.

Of course, then there is the matter of linking to the topic in a manner that encourages Music site users to view it.

Answer (score 1):

I added this meta question where we can add answers as documentation for ABCjs:

[Documentation for ABCjs](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2782/249)

This is inspired by Andrew's comment about how they did it ion Math.SE:

http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/174736