# Documentation for ABCjs

Tags: discussion, abcjs

This is a post that would act as documentation for the ABCjs syntax, which would be a good reference site for help on basic syntax.

Please add aswers here with basic examples for ABCjs syntax to make it easier to get into the world of writing music snippets on Music.SE.

Minimal requirement is to start the code block with `X:` and also specify key with `K:` before starting write the notes.
I also recommend specifying standard note lenght using `L:`. Default is eights that would be noted like this: `L: 1/8`.

## Example:

Code:

```
X: 1  
K: C  
L: 1/4   
ABc
```

Output:

```
X: 1
K: C
L: 1/4
ABc
```

---

## Links to ABCjs references:

- [ABCjs.net](https://abcjs.net/)
- [ABCjs quick editor](https://editor.drawthedots.com) - official editor recommended by ABCjs
- [ABCNotation.com examples](http://abcnotation.com/examples)
- [ABCNotation.com blog post on understanding the notation](http://abcnotation.com/blog/2010/01/31/how-to-understand-abc-the-basics/#further)
- [Steve Mansfield's ABC Notation Part 1](http://www.lesession.co.uk/abc/abc_notation.htm) - with links to a more advanced part
- [Steve Mansfield's Proposed Extensions to the ABC Notation](http://www.lesession.co.uk/abc/abc_extensions.htm) - some of those actually seem to be a part of the notation already, the single letter ones.
- [ABC specification](http://abcnotation.com/wiki/abc:standard:v2.1) Documentation for the ABC language.

We also have the formatting sandbox, which you can use to try out things for yourself:

[jTab and ABCjs Formatting Sandbox](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2581/jtab-and-abcjs-formatting-sandbox)

[ABCjs integration now available](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2574/abcjs-integration-now-available)

Comment: There is a sandbox on ABC page, which might be actually easier to use than the one on SE: https://www.abcjs.net/abcjs-editor.html

Answer (score 8):

```
X:1
T:Notes
M:C
L:1/4
K:C
C, D, E, F,|G, A, B, C|D E F G|A B c d|e f g a|b c' d' e'|f' g' a' b'|]
```

```
X:1
T:Notes
M:C
L:1/4
K:C
C, D, E, F,|G, A, B, C|D E F G|A B c d|e f g a|b c' d' e'|f' g' a' b'|]
```

Answer (score 8):

```
X:1
T:Note lengths and default note length
M:C
K:C
L:1/16
A/2 A/ A A2 A3 A4 A6 A7 A8 A12 A15 A16|]
L:1/8
A/4 A/2 A/ A A2 A3 A4 A6 A7 A8 A12 A15|]
L:1/4
A/8 A/4 A/2 A/ A A2 A3 A4 A6 A7|]
L:1/16
A2A2 (3 A2A2A2 (5 AAAAA (7 AAAAAAA |]
```

```
X:1
T:Note lengths and default note length
M:C
K:C
L:1/16
A/2 A/ A A2 A3 A4 A6 A7 A8 A12 A15 A16|]
L:1/8
A/4 A/2 A/ A A2 A3 A4 A6 A7 A8 A12 A15|]
L:1/4
A/8 A/4 A/2 A/ A A2 A3 A4 A6 A7|]
L:1/16
A2A2 (3 A2A2A2 (5 AAAAA (7 AAAAAAA |]
```

Answer (score 8):

```
X:1
T:Rests
M:C
K:C
L:1/4
A z G z/2 G/2 | A2 z2 | z3 G | z4 |]
```

```
X:1
T:Rests
M:C
K:C
L:1/4
A z G z/2 G/2 | A2 z2 | z3 G | z4 |]
```

Answer (score 8):

## Sharps, flats and naturals

To sharpen a note precede it with the circumflex or caret `^`
`^c`

To flatten a note precede it with an underscore `_`
`_B`

Double sharps are shown as `^^` and double flats as `__`

To naturalise a note precede it with an equals sign `=`
`=c`

So a scale of G major could be notated as `GABcde^fg`

```
X: 1  
K: C  
L: 1/4 
GABcde^fg
```

And a scale of G minor as `GA_Bcd_efg`

```
X: 1  
K: C  
L: 1/4 
GA_Bcd_efg
```

## Key

However: Just as standard Western musical notation has the key signature, so that the player automatically knows to (for example) play all F's as F♯ in the key of G, the same thing exists in abc, with the `K:` field.

Example in the key of B major with a B natural accident:

```
X: 1  
K: _B  
L: 1/4 
GA=BAGFED
```

```
X: 1  
K: _B  
L: 1/4 
GA=Bcdefg
```

Answer (score 6):

### Voices

#### Systems and clefs

To have multiple systems with parallel-running voices, first *declare* each system with a statement of the form `V:Vᴏɪᴄᴇ clef=Cʟᴇꜰ`. Then, when writing out the score, prefix each line with a reference to the voice it belongs to, in the form `[V:Vᴏɪᴄᴇ]`.

```
X:1
K:C
V:V1 clef=treble
V:V2 clef=treble
V:Va clef=alto
V:Vc clef=bass
[V:V1] c
[V:V2] E
[V:Va] G,
[V:Vc] C,
```

```
    X:1
    K:C
    V:V1 clef=treble
    V:V2 clef=treble
    V:Va clef=alto
    V:Vc clef=bass
    [V:V1] c
    [V:V2] E
    [V:Va] G,
    [V:Vc] C,
```

#### Multiple voices in a system

You can also have indepent voices within a single system. That requires, in addition to the declaration of voices with their clefs (which must in this case match!) a grouping-declaration in the form `%%score (Vᴏɪᴄᴇ₁ Vᴏɪᴄᴇ₂)`.

```
X:1
K:Am
%%score (T1 T2)
V:T1 clef=treble
V:T2 clef=treble
[V:T1] c3  B c
[V:T2] AG FG A
```

```
    X:1
    K:Am
    %%score (T1 T2)
    V:T1 clef=treble
    V:T2 clef=treble
    [V:T1] c3  B c
    [V:T2] AG FG A
```

#### Chords within a single voice

To just write simultaneous notes of the same length, which needn't be considered as belonging to individual voices, you can put those notes in square brackets. Note length can be specified after the closing bracket and will hold for all notes in the chord.

```
X:1
K:C
G [GB] [EAc]2 [GB] [FBd] [Ec]2
```

```
    X:1
    K:C
    G [GB] [EAc]2 [GB] [FBd] [Ec]2
```

Answer (score 2):

**CHANGING KEY SIGNATURE**

```
X:0
K:C
CDEFGAB | [K:Cmin] C'BAGFED | C
```

```
X:0
K:C
CDEFGAB | [K:Cmin] C'BAGFED | C
```

Comment: Note that you must use the bracket notation.

Answer (score 0):

**IRRATIONAL TIME SIGNATURES**

```
X:0
K:none
M:3/5
L:1/4
A B c | [M:3+2/7] A B c B2 |
```

```
X:0
K:none
M:3/5
L:1/4
A B c | [M:3+2/7] A B c B2 |
```

Comment: I would note that these time signatures are not irrational, but rather their denominators are not powers of two.

Comment: @phoog The term "irrational time signature" is separate from "irrational numbers". In the time signature case, it refers to any non-power-of-two time signature. See, for example, [Unusual time signatures?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/33382/unusual-time-signatures). The situation would be much improved had the theorist who coined the term consulted with one of us first.

Comment: This example doesn't seem right. It's showing up as 4/4 in my browser.

Comment: @A.R. That's likely due to a long-standing problem with ABCjs on the site. Try doing a hard refresh of your browser.