# How to get notes and staves to show up without images?

Tags: support, music-notation

I noticed with the second answer on my polytonality question, that the answerer was able to get notes and staves to show up using some kind of code instead of images. I am wanting to post a question about whether I should end my trio piece with the violin doing a double stop and am thinking of using code to show the notes and staves(so in my case, I will need to do 1 grand staff, 1 bass staff, and 1 treble staff).

Problem is, I have no idea what kind of code it is or how it goes from code to music notation. The only thing I know is that I would have to use the preformatted text in the question where I want to show the music notation.

Here is the link to the polytonality question in case you want to look at it:

[Special case of polytonality, why does it sound like a single key?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/80341/special-case-of-polytonality-why-does-it-sound-like-a-single-key/80354#comment134657_80354)

Comment: @DoktorMayhem maybe https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2782/documentation-for-abcjs contains more direct answers to the question?

Comment: Thanks @topomorto - I thought that one existed but couldn't find it. Favourited now :-)